# C++: vector <pair<vector<int>,int> >

Tags: c++, vector, int, std-pair

This is what I am aiming to do...

```
vector < pair<vector<int>,int> > var_name (x, pair <vector<int>(y),int>);
```

Where x is the size of the vector var_name and y is the size of the vector inside the pair.

The above statement doesn't work because the pair template only allows constants. How can I go about getting both my vectors to size to x and y respectively?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector<pair<vector<int>,int> > var_name(x, make_pair(vector<int>(y), 0));
```

Comment: Nice! make_pair... why didn't I think of that?

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it as:

```
pair<vector<int>,int> value(vector<int>(y), 0);
vector<pair<vector<int>,int> > var_name(x, value);
```

If you like your own syntax, then you should be doing this:

```
vector<pair<vector<int>,int> > var_name(x, std::make_pair(vector<int>(y), 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `make_pair` from `<utility>` to construct the pair you wish to initialize your `vector` with. For example:

`vector< pair<vector<int>,int> > var_name(x, make_pair(vector<int>(y), 42))`

or call the `pair<vector<int>,int>` constructor directly (as it looks like you're trying to):

`vector< pair<vector<int>,int> > var_name(x, pair<vector<int>,int>(vector<int>(y), 0))`

Answer (score 0):

`pair<vector<int>,int>` is the name of a type. For the initialization, you need a value.

You get a value by calling the constructor of the type (the same way that, at the top level of the statement, you're doing for `var_name`). Since this is creating a value in-line in an expression, rather than initializing a variable, there is no variable name, and we just write something like `pair<vector<int>,int>(...)`. The `...` are the arguments for the constructor (putting `(y)` anywhere inside the angle brackets is illogical). In our case, we want the first value to be a vector of length y, and the second value to be... 0, I assume.

So we get `pair<vector<int>,int>(vector<int>(y), 0)`. That's rather unwieldy, which is why the standard library provides the template function `std::make_pair`. It gets around the fact that template arguments can't be inferred for constructors, by using a free function (which **can** do inference with template arguments) to call the constructor.

Thus the above shortens to `make_pair(vector<int>(y), 0)`, which, when substituted into the rest of the line, gives Benjamin Lindley's answer.